# Creating and retrieving from a multi dimensional dictionary with Python while looping through a tabular data?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create following structure :
Tom :{start_row: 1 ,end_row:3},Sam:{start_row:4,end_row:5}, Mike:{start_row:6,end_row:8}

The data I have in excel is 
  Tom|A|
  Tom|X|
  Tom|Y|
  Sam|z| 
  ..

The code i am using is

```
all_guys_list = {}
start_end_dict = {"start_row": 0, "end_row": 0}
for xl_row in range(2,xlworksheet.max_row+1):
    present_guy_name = xlworksheet.cell(row=xl_row,column=1).value
    if present_guy_name not in all_guys_list:
        all_guys_list[present_guy_name] = 0
        start_end_dict["start_row"]=xl_row
    else:
        start_end_dict["end_row"] = xl_row
        all_guys_list[present_guy_name]=start_end_dict
print(all_guys_list)
```

the output is :
{'TOM': {'start_row': 6, 'end_row': 8}, 'SAM': {'start_row': 6, 'end_row': 8}, 'MIKE': {'start_row': 6, 'end_row': 8}}

So at the end of each loop, start_end_dict is being assigned to all the keys of all_guy_list , which is wrong . As a result start and end row value of Mike is assigned to all the guys .  How can i fix this ?

Also , I have to select outer keys in loop and iterate from start to end row for each guy and pick other values from excel . Please help me with this .

Answer (score 0):

This happens because all the elements in `all_guys_list` are the very same `start_end_dict` you have created and continiously modify. You should reset (re-initialize) `start_end_dict` inside for loop:

```
all_guys_list = {}
for xl_row in range(2,xlworksheet.max_row+1):
    start_end_dict = {"start_row": 0, "end_row": 0}
    ...
```

Another approach is to copy `start_end_dict` every time you finished with the current `present_guy_name`:

```
all_guys_list = {}
start_end_dict = {"start_row": 0, "end_row": 0}
for xl_row in range(2,xlworksheet.max_row+1):
    ...
        ...
        all_guys_list[present_guy_name] = start_end_dict.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks , the second method did worked but not the first one . First one is make all the start_row as = 0

Comment: @Rohit Both methods are essentially the same and both should work. Anyway, glad your problem fixed.